# How can I call only one line of an html file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to call just one line of an html file? For example, if you have this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        This is a test string.
        This is another test string.
        This is the final test string.
    </body>
</html>
```

Could you call only the first string, "This is a test string.", out of this file? I thought there was a way to include with php and put "example.html:5", but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does "call" mean to you? HTML files are not executable.

Comment: Are you doing this in the client or server? You have both Javascript and PHP tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not the best approach for huge files, but would work fine for your example:

```
//read file in to array
$lines=file('file.html');

//line 5 (array index start at 0)
echo $lines[4];
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently no one else knows what calling something is.

Comment: well i just guessed, the other posters are right, this is not a clear question.